# Error while Scaffold-DbContext in .NET 7.0 with PostgreSQL: 'The specified deps.json does not exist

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, maui

I am trying to scaffold the models from an existing PostgreSQL database in my .NET 7.0 project using Entity Framework Core's Scaffold-DbContext command. However, I keep encountering the error message: "The specified deps.json does not exist." I have verified my connection string, installed the required packages, and tried both PowerShell and dotnet ef approaches, but the issue persists.

Steps I have taken:

Checked my .NET SDK version (dotnet --version) and confirmed it's 7.0.
Installed Entity Framework Core (dotnet ef --version) and Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL packages.
Verified the connection string in my appsettings.json file.
Tried both the Scaffold-DbContext PowerShell cmdlet and dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command.

Comment: Try EF Core Power Tools, does not need to build your project